# Как проверить есть ли у класса Т метод foo?

Tags: c++

Есть ли возможность в `C++` написать что-то похожее на это:

```
template<class T>
void f(T a)  {
  if ( Существет метод a.foo ) {
    a.foo();
  } else {
    myfoo(a);
  }
}
```

Т.е. функция должна вести себя по разному в зависимости от того есть у класса T метод `foo` или нет.

Comment: никак. В с++ нет методов, поэтому нет классов, у которого есть хотя бы один метод вообще. Не верите - читайте стандарт. Но если закрыть на это глаза и говорить о функциях класса, то есть способ - создайте абстрактный класс, который содержит нужную функцию и наследуйтесь от него. Дальше все проверки будут элементарны.

Comment: можно через специализацию проверить что есть у класса метод, и таким образом выбрать нужную имплементацию, а в дефолтовой сделать вызов своей функции

Comment: Сейчас найду дубликат, момент.

Comment: с++ нет, в COM интерфейсе, можно через IDispatch проверить, в borland можно через VCL  проверить если она published. У МS есть аналог vcl там тоже можно. Можно самому создать виртуальную ф-цию проверяющую имя ф-ции.

Comment: @VladD, не совсем это дубликат, выяснение наличия функции здесь лишь частью задачи является.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Это делается так:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A{
    void foo(){}
};

struct B{};

template<class T>
struct Test{
    typedef void(T::*P)(void);

    template<class U, P = &U::foo>
    struct True{char dummy[2];};

    typedef char False;

    static False detect(...);

    template<class U>
    static True<U> detect(U*);

    static const bool exists = (sizeof(False) != sizeof(detect(static_cast<T*>(0))));
};


int main(){
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Test<B>::exists << std::endl; //false
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << Test<A>::exists << std::endl; //true
}
```

Теперь о том, что же здесь творится. В коде используется идиома под названием SFINAE. Аббревиатура SFINAE расшифровывается как *substitution failure is not an error* и означает следующее: при определении перегрузок функции **ошибочные инстанциации шаблонов не вызывают ошибку компиляции, а отбрасываются из списка кандидатов на наиболее подходящую перегрузку**.

Теперь посмотрим как будет себя вести этот код. В классе `Test` определено два типа `True` и `False`. Их важным свойством является то, что **`sizeof(False) != sizeof(True<T>)`**.

Так же в нашем распоряжении есть два метода `detect`. Первый принимает указатель на `T`, второй принимает произвольное количество аргументов(эллипсис). **Эллипсис является всеядным, и в тоже время обладает самым низким приоритетом при выборе перегрузки**.
При вызове `detect(static_cast<T*>(0)` компилятор пробует подобрать подходящую перегрузку. Более высоким приоритетом обладает шаблонная версия `detect`. Но если у типа `T` не окажется метода `void foo()`, то инстанцирование шаблона провалится. Но как мы помним *substitution failure is not an error*. Компилятор отдаст предпочтение эллипсису(тореточие).

Узнать какая версия `detect` была выбрана мы можем по типу возвращаемого значения. А отличить типы мы можем по их размеру.

Обратите внимание, в коде нет реализации методов `detect`. Тут используется тот факт что **`sizeof` не вычисляет значение выражения, сразу извлекает тип**. Таким образом методы `detect` никогда не будут вызваны.

В итоге в переменной `exists` окажется `true` если у типа `T` есть метод `void foo()`.

Весь код выполняется на этапе компиляции, и не дает никаких накладных расходов.

Так же этот код скомпилировался онлайн-компилятором в режиме совместимости с C++98

**UPD:** В комментариях мне намекнули, что это не решает вашей проблемы. В какой-то мере это так. Полученное значение нельзя просто использовать в `if`-е, так как это приведет к ошибке компиляции. Нам нужен аналог `if`, который бы отрабатывал на этапе компиляции. В роли такого `if`-а может выступить специализация шаблонов:

```
template<class T, bool b = Test<T>::exists>
struct Foo;

template<class T>
struct Foo<T, true>{
    static void foo(const T &t){
        t.foo();
    }
};

template<class T>
struct Foo<T, false>{
    static void foo(const T &t){
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Структура `Foo` имеет две специализации. Первая для случая `Test<T>::exists == true`, вторая для `false`. Ну и небольшая вишенка на торте для удобства, не добавляющая ничего нового кроме автоматического вывода типа аргументов:

```
template<class T>
void foo(const T &t){
    Foo<T>::foo(t);
}
```

Теперь `main` примет такой вид:

```
int main(){
    A a;
    B b;

    foo(a); //A::foo
    foo(b); //foo
}
```

[Полный пример](http://cpp.sh/6ixrv)

Comment: Теперь другое дело, +1.

Answer (score 7):

Всё ниженаписанное будет работать для C++, версии 14-го года минимум.
У Вас, по сути, две проблемы: первая, это определить есть ли у класса функция, и вторая вызвать функцию в зависимости от того, есть ли она. 
Первая проблема решается довольно просто:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct HasFoo: std::false_type
{};

template<typename T>
struct HasFoo<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<T>().foo()), void>::value>>: std::true_type
{};
template<typename T>
constexpr bool HasFoo_v = HasFoo<T>::value;
```

Используется это так:

```
constexpr bool hasFoo = HasFoo_v<ClassToTest>;
```

Давайте допустим, что у нас следующие входные данные:

```
struct A 
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "From class foo!\n";
    }
};

struct B {};

void foo(B)
{
    std::cout << "From standalone foo!\n";
}
```

Теперь, нам надо как-то вызывать разные функции, в зависимости от наличия функции `foo`. Тут перед нами встаёт первая проблема: если бы на дворе был 17 год, то вполне вероятно, что мы могли бы написать как-то так:

```
A a;
if constexpr (HasFoo_v<A>) { a.foo(); }
else { foo(a); }
```

Но у нас всё ещё 2016, поэтому придётся пойти другой дорогой: напишем свой constexpr if(жалкое подобие, хотя бы). Вот к такой реализации я пришёл:

```
template<bool B, typename F>
struct ConditioanlCall
{
    ConditioanlCall(F function)
    {}
};

template<typename F>
struct ConditioanlCall<true, F>
{
    ConditioanlCall(F function)
    {
        auto ignore = false;
        function(ignore);
    }
};

template<bool B, typename F>
void callConditional(F&& function)
{
    ConditioanlCall<B, F>{std::forward<F>(function)};
}

#define CONSTEXPR_IF(condition, action) \
    callConditional<condition>([&](auto) action);
```

Используется это так:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    CONSTEXPR_IF(!HasFoo_v<B>, {foo(b);});
    CONSTEXPR_IF(HasFoo_v<A>, {a.foo();});

    return 0;
}
```

Полный код можно найти по [ссылке](http://ideone.com/KdOsp0).

Comment: Как всё сложно. Лучше подожду 2017 :)