# Ошибка компиляции при обобщении типов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть некоторая функция, принимающая в качестве аргумента вектор любого типа через шаблон.

```
template <typename T>
bool my_function( const std::vector< T >& vec, bool pairs ) {
    if( pairs )
        return vec[0].first < vec[1].first;
    else
        return vec[0] < vec[1];
}
```

У функции есть второй аргумент, показывающий, передается ли функции вектор типа std::pair<>, например, std::pair< int, int >. Пример вызова:

```
std::vector< std::pair< int, int > > v( std::pair< int, int >(0, 0),
                                        std::pair< int, int >(1, 1) );
bool res = my_function( v, true );
```

Этот код компилируется нормально, но если теперь где-нибудь в другом  месте вызвать эту функцию с вектором просто целочисленных значений (а не пар) и флагом false, что логически должно работать правильно, на этапе компиляции возникнет ошибка:

```
std::vector< int > v2( 0, 1 );
bool res2 = my_function( v2, false );

//////
error: request for member ‘first’ in ‘vec.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<int, std::allocator<int> >(0)’, which is of non-class type ‘const value_type {aka const int}’
```

Попытка исправить ситуацию через dynamic_cast не увенчалась успехом:

```
template <typename T>
bool my_function( const std::vector< T >& vec, bool pairs ) {
    if( pairs ) {
        const std::pair< int, int >* v_0 = dynamic_cast< const std::pair< int, int >* >(&vec[0]);
        const std::pair< int, int >* v_1 = dynamic_cast< const std::pair< int, int >* >(&vec[1]);
        return v_0->first < v_1->first;
    }
    else
        return vec[0] < vec[1];
}

/////
error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘& vec.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<int, std::allocator<int> >(0)’ (of type ‘const value_type* {aka const int*}’) to type ‘const struct std::pair<int, int>*’ (source is not a pointer to class)
```

Как успокоить компилятор? Может быть, есть способ более изящно обобщить типы, без использования второго параметра pairs? Варианты с typeid тоже не работали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему бы вам не воспользоваться специализацией:

```
template<typename T>
bool my_function( const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
        return vec[0] < vec[1];
}

template<typename T>
bool my_function( const std::vector<pair<T,T>>& vec)
{
        return vec[0].first < vec[1].first;
}
```

Можно и простой перегрузкой, кстати...

Comment: это да, но интересно, существует ли способ именно в одной функции реализовать такое обобщение типов?

Comment: Как это работает? Ведь вектор пар подходит и по первому шаблону.

Comment: @layer19, лучше не стоит так делать. Я уже задавал похожий вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579570/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%A2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-foo

Comment: @pank Почитайте о специализации - в данном случае второй шаблон точнее отвечает переданному типу. Что до вашего совета так не делать - интересно бы понять, 1. почему и 2. а как по-вашему надо поступать?...

Comment: @Harry здесь приведен просто пример с локализацией проблемы. На самом деле функция намного сложнее и объемнее, а строка сравнения находится глубоко внутри лямбда-выражения... Не хочется дублировать большой объем кода из-за одной строки.

Comment: @layer19 Представьте себя на месте компилятора. Прежде чем включать оптимизатор, ему нужно скомпилировать для вашего типа `vector<T>` обращение `v[0].first`. Как вы это сделаете - если там такого поля и близко нет?...

Comment: @Harry, лучше сделать так как вы предложили. Не стоит делать так, как хочет @layer19, потому что придётся написать ещё больше кода. Пока что. Ждём `constexpr if`.

Comment: @layer19 Тогда вы уверены, что это не [XY-проблема](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Может, саму исходную задачу следует решать иначе?

Comment: @pank А, вот что... извините, я вас сначала неправильно понял...

Comment: @Harry, прощаю)

Comment: @Harry да, суть проблемы понятна, потому и была идея с dynamic_cast - дать компилятору понять, что все решится при конкретном вызове. Собственно, вариант с reinterpret_cast работает. Но нет ли более безопасного пути?

Comment: @Harry насчет XY - на первый взгляд так не кажется, но подумать стоит.

Comment: @pank вот-вот, нельзя ли справиться синтаксическими средствами на стандарте С++11?

Comment: Ну какой `dynamic_cast` к шаблонам? Где у вас наследование, виртуальные функции? `reinterpret_cast` - ну не в этом случае! Поймите, сама идея **кроме типа передавать в шаблонную функцию переменную, этот тип указывающую** - нонсенс!...

Comment: @Harry полностью согласен с Вами - второй параметр это костыль. Изначально была идея написать именно обобщенную функцию. Что же, пока, как я вижу, можно лишь изменить подход и использовать специализацию, чтобы не выворачивать код наизнанку.

Comment: На худой конец можно вынести это сравнение или что там у вас в отдельную небольшую функцию и специализировать только ее.